# How to append HTML from Controller into directive template AngularJS - error Can't interpolate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, compilation, append, interpolation

I have a function in my AngularJS controller:

```
//some stuff from controller

var variable1;
var variable2; 

$scope.setTitle = function () { 
            if ( //sth) {
                variable1 = "string"
                return variable1;
            }
            else {
                (function () {
                    //setting the variable2 - it will be the HTML code
                      variable2 = angular.element(document.querySelector('titleID'));
                      variable2.append(title);                        
                })();
            return variable2;
            }
        };
```

I'm getting the `title` from JSON file and it looks like:

```
 title = "Return product: <span data-ng-bind=\"productRet.ID\" />"
```

I have to use the JSON file, because I have a big "tree" inside this JSON file, and the `title` is different according to what will happen inside the `function` in `else` statement

I'm calling `setTitle()` in my template in directive:

```
.directive('myDirective', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var template = { 
                             <!-- a lot of HTML -->
                             + "<div id=\"titleID\">"
                                 + "<span class=\"navbar-brand\" > {{setTitle()}} </span>"
                             + </div>
                           };

            templateObj = $compile(template)(scope);
            element.append(templateObj);
            }
        }
     }]);
```

If the result from `setTitle()` is the `variable1` everything is fine. The problem is when the result is `variable2` because I'm getting an error:

> "[$interpolate:interr] Can't interpolate:  {{setTitle()}}
>   Error:
>   [$parse:isecdom] Referencing DOM nodes in Angular expressions is
>   disallowed! Expression: setTitle()

How to properly insert the HTML code from variable2 into my template??

Comment: You should not manipulate DOM in controllers. It is totally against AngularJS philosophy. Move to directive link function. Or better put it in the HTML through `ng-show`, `ng-click`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
(function () {
                    //setting the variable2 - it will be the HTML code
                      var variable2 = angular.element(document.querySelector('titleID'));
                      variable2.append(title);                        
                })();
            return variable2;
```

variable2 isn't available outside of the function scope.
Try something like this:

```
var variable2;
(function () {
    //setting the variable2 - it will be the HTML code
    variable2 = angular.element(document.querySelector('titleID'));
    variable2.append(title);                        
})();
return variable2;
```

Comment: Yes yes, it's my mistake, but even if it's outside the scope I'm getting an error